# Программное нажатие ссылок в браузере

Tags: delphi

Столкнулся с проблемой: не могу программно "кликнуть" по "кнопке" в `Webbrowser` или ссылке в виде кнопки, если у нее свойство `href` содержит скрипт. Ссылки вида: `a href="/index.php` нажимаются отлично (`...Item(i).Click;`). А вот подобные не хотят: `a href="javascript: quick_login()"`, т.е. что-то на странице происходит, но результата нет.
Попытки эмуляции событий `onclick`, `onmouseup`, `onmousedown` не помогают.

Comment: содержание функции quick_login() можно взглянуть?

Comment: Данная функция приведена для примера, на целевой странице функция другая. Есть веб-приложение на Ajax, в нем вложенный фрем с формой поиска, данные ссылки это результаты, которые выводит форма если их несколько; когда результат один, проблем нет. 

При клике заменяет содержание вложенного фрейма информацией для найденного объекта. )

Comment: Для того и сделано на JavaScript, чтобы школьники не писали кликерорв.

Анализируйте, что страница отправляет к серверу и каким методом, и делайте такую же отправку, и не используйте в `TWebBrowser`.

Да и анализировать заголовки тоже не помешает, поймете, на какомм уровне есть возможность работы с Ajax.

Comment: А `Navigate('javascript:...');` не работает разве?

Comment: Всем спасибо за советы, в общем выход нашел нестандартный... даже несколько извращенный.
 Собственно из-за чего не срабатывал Item(i).Click; -> из-за того что у ссылки нет свойства onclick.
А задать данное свойство самому мне ничего не мешает. Т.е.
 1. находим элемент
 2. читаем свойство href
 3. создаем у элемента новое свойство onclick (значение берем из href)
 4. кликаем...

Answer (score 1):

Собственно, смотрим, разбираем. Оно работает, проверено) Учим JS и ищем ссылку как-нибудь, хоть по тексту (innerHTML), хоть по порядковому номеру, хоть как хотите)

*Данный код заходит на Хэшкод, ищет кнопку "Вопросы" и тыкает в нее. CMD в таком виде только для удобства чтения + учитывайте максимальную длину URL, вроде 1024. Если нужно больше, запускаем по частям (сперва `window.myFunc = function() {alert("lol");}`, потом `window.myFunc();`)*

*Да, пробовал на Delphi7, если что.*

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
WebBrowser1.Navigate('http://hashcode.ru/');

end;

procedure TForm1.WebBrowser1DocumentComplete(Sender: TObject;
  const pDisp: IDispatch; var URL: OleVariant);
var cmd: string;
begin
if (URL='http://hashcode.ru/')  then begin
  cmd := 'javascript:'
    + '(function(){'
    + 'var l=document.getElementsByTagName("a");'
    + 'for(var i=0;i<l.length;i++)'
    +   'if (l[i].innerHTML=="Вопросы")'
    +     'l[i].click();'
    + '})();';
  WebBrowser1.Navigate(cmd);
  end;
end;
```

CMD для авторизации вконтакта (*правильным как бы намекаю - делать так не надо, но уметь - обязательно*)

```
  cmd := 'javascript:'
    + '(function(){'
    + 'document.getElementById("quick_email").value="my@email.com";'
    + 'document.getElementById("quick_pass").value="myVeryLongPassword";'
    + 'setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("quick_login_form").submit();}, 10);'
    + '})();';
```